# ORACLE Search All Tables of a String with BLOB Column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, blob

I'm trying to search using a String for all tables but it didn't seem to work in BLOB columns. I got this procedure from a forum. It's working in searching string but not in BLOB.
Can you please help me please?

```
create or replace procedure find_string( p_str in varchar2 )
authid current_user
as
l_query    long;
l_case     long;
l_runquery boolean;
l_tname    varchar2(30);
l_cname    varchar2(30);
l_x        number;
begin
dbms_application_info.set_client_info( '%' || upper(p_str) || '%' );

for x in (select * from user_tables )
loop
l_query := 'select ''' || x.table_name || ''', $$
                         from ' || x.table_name || '
                       where rownum = 1 and ( 1=0 ';
           l_case := 'case ';
           l_runquery := FALSE;
           for y in ( select *
                        from user_tab_columns
                       where table_name = x.table_name
                    )
           loop
               l_runquery := TRUE;
               l_query := l_query || ' or upper(' || y.column_name ||
                          ') like userenv(''client_info'') ';
              l_case := l_case || ' when upper(' || y.column_name ||
                         ') like userenv(''client_info'') then ''' ||
                         y.column_name || '''';
           end loop;
           if ( l_runquery )
           then
               l_case := l_case || ' else NULL end';
               l_query := replace( l_query, '$$', l_case ) || ')';
              begin
                   execute immediate l_query into l_tname, l_cname;
                   dbms_output.put_line
                   ( 'Found in ' || l_tname || '.' || l_cname );
               exception
                   when no_data_found then
                      /*select 0 into l_x from dual;*/
                      dbms_output.put( '.');
               end;
           end if;

      end loop;
   end;
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot search for strings within a BLOB column using the normal SQL String operations. You would need to use the `dbms_lob` package to achieve your goal.

Refer to [this](http://blog.sbw.be/2006/09/13/oracle-search-inside-blob-content/comment-page-1/) link for an example of how it is to be done. There are plenty of examples on Google too which can guide you further.